# Moment.js comparison always returns false

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm struggling with a strange problem but let's first talk about what I'm trying to achieve. I am developing an from-to date and time picker and now I'm stuck on the part where you check if the first value (from) is not after the second value (to). I'm using moment.js which is working just fine.. except the three queries: `isBefore`, `isAfter` and `isSame`.

My code looks like this `if(moment(from).isAfter(to)) { ... }` and it returns `false`. Actually I went further with the tests and checked all/most possible combinations. Here is the output:

```
EARLY  equals  "31.12.2018 11:00"
LATE   equals  "01.12.2018 10:00"

LATE   is before   EARLY  =  false   (should equal true)
EARLY  is after    LATE   =  false   (should equal true)
LATE   is after    EARLY  =  false
EARLY  is before   LATE   =  false
EARLY  is same as  LATE   =  false
LATE   is same as  EARLY  =  false
```

I have no idea what the problem could be. I'm 100% that both of these variables are strings and I'm parsing both of them as a `moment()` and I can even programmatically add and subtract days, months, etc. without any errors.

It's been a long day trying to compare two damn dates. Now I hope the community will be smarter than me! :D

Comment: How about the code that is generating the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [moment.js docs](https://devdocs.io/moment):

> The following return `false`:
>
> - `invalid.isAfter(another)`
> - `invalid.isAfter(invalid)`
> - `another.isAfter(invalid)`
> - `invalid.isBefore(another)`
> - `invalid.isBefore(invalid)`
> - `another.isBefore(invalid)`

Odds are, one (or both) of your dates is (or are) invalid.

My guess is that you're parsing your dates incorrectly. [Docs](https://devdocs.io/moment/#parsing-string-format) suggest using String + format for non-standard date formats.

```
const incorrect = '31.12.2017 11:00';
console.log(moment(incorrect)); // invalid date

const correct = '31.12.2017 11:00';
console.log(moment(correct, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm')); // valid date
```

Comment: Hmm yes, it might be the case. I'm going to test that when I get home. Thanks 

Comment: After hours of failure, I've tried this `moment(moment("31.12.2018 12:00").format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm")).isBefore(moment("01.12.2018 12:00").format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"))` and it also returned `false`.

Comment: @MikeEling try `moment("31.12.2018 12:00", "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm").isBefore(moment("01.12.2018 12:00", "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"))`?

Comment: This solution is actually working! Thank you very much, I appreciate your help ☺

Comment: mine is always returning false too. Both dates in the same format. Format is supplied to moment. I am also calling .isValid before comparing them. Im at a loss.

Comment: Eventually I realized lowercase 'mm' is not months. Make sure to use uppercase.